# How can I use seleium test case in groovy?

Tags: selenium, groovy

How can I use seleium test case in groovy? such as clinking on links.

test case

```
<html>
...
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
           <td>open</td>
           <td>https://url.web:8010/</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
           <td>clickAndWait</td>
           <td>link=service=homeLink</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
           <td>clickAndWait</td>
           <td>link=name=contentLink,service=Queue</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
           <td>clickAndWait</td>
           <td>link=BackLink</td>
  </tr>

  ...
```

GROVVY script

```
// Setup credentials
def String[] credentials = new String[2]
credentials[0] = "username"
credentials[1] = "password"
def cred = [(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS):credentials]

// Setup JMX connection with credentials
def serviceURL = 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://url.web:8010/jmxrmi'
def service = JmxFactory.connect(new JmxUrl(serverUrl), cred).MBeanServerConnection
```

How to use click and wait from selenium script

Answer (score 0):

Groovy is essentially Java underneath. So a GroovyTest case you would structure exactly like a JUnit3 test.

```
class SampleTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    void test_FirstTest() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
        driver.get(some url)
        .....
    }
}
```

If you like, you can have a look at several sample tests that I have written in Groovy, [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/sebase/code/HEAD/tree/sebase-groovy/src/test/groovy/net/sourceforge/sebase/demos/).